# Nested JSON - Join sub-object

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I remove sub-objects?

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "desc": "SOME PRODUCT",
    "codigo": "CODE-28",
    "codigoBarras": "2000000001",
    "unidade": "PCT",
    "price": "24.15",
    "current_inventory": [{
        "2kg": "5",
        "5kg": "5",
        "10kg": "5",
        "20kg": "5",
        "productId": "1"
     }]
 }]

[{
    "id": "1",
    "desc": "SOME PRODUCT",
    "codigo": "CODE-28",
    "codigoBarras": "2000000001",
    "unidade": "PCT",
    "price": "24.15",
    "current_inventory_2kg": "5",
    "current_inventory_5kg": "5",
    "current_inventory_10kg": "5",
    "current_inventory_20kg": "5",
}]
```

Comment: What should happen if current_inventory has more than one object inside that array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Object.keys()` and a `forEach` loop

```js
var x =[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "desc": "SOME PRODUCT",
        "codigo": "CODE-28",
        "codigoBarras": "2000000001",
        "unidade": "PCT",
        "price": "24.15",
        "current_inventory": [
            {
                "2kg": "5",
                "5kg": "5",
                "10kg": "5",
                "20kg": "5",
                "productId": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
x[0].current_inventory.forEach(e=>{
Object.keys(e).forEach(j=>{
x[0]['current_inventory_'+j]=e[j];
})
delete x[0].current_inventory
})
console.log(x)
```

Comment: How I can apply this in each objetct?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.entries` and `reduce` will simplify.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    desc: "SOME PRODUCT",
    codigo: "CODE-28",
    codigoBarras: "2000000001",
    unidade: "PCT",
    price: "24.15",
    current_inventory: [
      {
        "2kg": 5,
        "5kg": 5,
        "10kg": 5,
        "20kg": 5,
        productId: 1
      }
    ]
  }
];

const [first] = data;

const updated = Object.entries(first).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    value.forEach(item =>
      Object.entries(item).forEach(
        ([cKey, cValue]) => (acc[`${key}_${cKey}`] = cValue)
      )
    );
  } else {
    acc[key] = value;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(updated);
```

Answer (score 0):

**THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!**

Solved using the code below:

data is de object

estoqueFracionado is the sub-object

```
              for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
                    value.estoqueFracionado.forEach (e => {
                        Object.keys(e).forEach(j => {
                            value['estoqueFracionado_' + j] = e[j]
                        })
                        delete value.estoqueFracionado
                    })
                }
```